# How to stop/terminate a python script from running with BackgroundScheduler() of APScheduler

Tags: python, exit, execution, terminate, apscheduler

I'm trying to stop the while loop execution from inside the foo() function. I've tried exit() / sys.exit without success. How can I stop completely the execution of the program from inside the function?

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import sys

def foo(stop = False):
    print('Function foo executed')
    if stop: 
        sys.exit

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler() 
dd = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)
scheduler.add_job(foo, 'date', run_date=dd, args=[True])
scheduler.start()

while True:
    print('Inside the loop')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use psutil

```py
import psutil

psutil.Process().terminate()
```

From the doc,
`psutil.Process()`     If PID is omitted current process PID (os.getpid()) is used.

Be aware terminate will leave with exit code 0. If you want other exit code, you can use `send_signal()` or even `kill()`

Comment: This was so helpful.  I had tried what OP did, I tried a listener thinking I could sys.exit() from there, but none of it worked.  This `psutil.Process().terminate()` is the way to terminate no matter what thread situation you're in.