# How to exit from script with apscheduler?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, apscheduler

I have the following script to launch a telegram bot. It also contains a scheduler that checks for a change in the used token. If the token in the database has changed, then the script should exit. But that doesn't happen. How to fix it?

```
import os
import sys

import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
django.setup()

from telegram import Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from tgbot.dispatcher import setup_dispatcher
from tgusers.models import TGBot


def check_token(tg_token):
    current_token = TGBot.objects.filter(active=True).first().token
    if not current_token:
        print("No active token found in the database. Restarting the bot.")
        sys.exit(1)

    if tg_token != current_token:
        print("Detected token change. Restarting the bot.")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print("No change detected. Continuing")
        return


def run_polling():
    from config.utils import TELEGRAM_TOKEN as tg_token
    """Run bot in polling mode"""
    updater = Updater(tg_token, use_context=True)

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp = setup_dispatcher(dp)

    bot_info = Bot(tg_token).get_me()
    bot_link = f"https://t.me/{bot_info['username']}"

    print(f"Polling of '{bot_link}' has started")

    updater.start_polling()

    # Initialize the scheduler and add the check_token job
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(check_token, "interval", seconds=3, args=(tg_token,))
    scheduler.start()

    updater.idle()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_polling()
```

console output:

```
No change detected. Continuing
No change detected. Continuing
Detected token change. Restarting the bot.
Detected token change. Restarting the bot.
Detected token change. Restarting the bot.
Detected token change. Restarting the bot.
Detected token change. Restarting the bot.
Detected token change. Restarting the bot.
Detected token change. Restarting the bot.
```

Comment: To exit [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65204671/how-to-stop-terminate-a-python-script-from-running-with-backgroundscheduler-of). However, it would be a better design to just restart the bot and not the whole application.